# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type UserProfile)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I was trying to build an inventory panel,
Am not able to run save_model() in IssuedAdmin in admin.py

I was trying to get the username of the person who has issued the item

*In InventoryIssued class :*

1. User represents the person who issued it.
2. get_users is the list of all the users present in UserProfile

***models.py***

```py
class InventoryIssued(models.Model):
    """Inventory Issued to person """

    get_user_type = models.ForeignKey(RoleOfUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user          = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                     null=True, blank=True,
                                     on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                     )

    get_users     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'issued')

    item_name     = models.ManyToManyField(InventoryPresent)
    date          = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    quantity      = models.IntegerField(default = '1')

    status        = [("APP","Approved"),
                    ("DEC","Declined"),]

    item_status   = models.CharField(choices = status, blank=False, max_length = 3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_users

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Inventory Issued'


class User_manager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, name, 
                    phone_number,password):

        email    = self.normalize_email(email)
        user     = self.model(username=username, email=email, name=name,
                            phone_number=phone_number,)

        user.is_active = True
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, name, 
                        phone_number,password):

        user = self.create_user(username=username, email=email, name=name,
                                phone_number=phone_number, password=password)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff     = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class UserProfile(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):

    username    = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True,)
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=32, unique=True,)

    name        = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False,)

    user_type   = models.ForeignKey(
                    RoleOfUser, 
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                    null=True, blank=True)

    phone_number = PhoneField(unique=True,
                            blank=False,)

    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)

    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email","name",
                        "phone_number",]

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    objects = User_manager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        """ Retrive full Name """
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

---

***admin.py***

```py
@admin.register(InventoryIssued)
class IssuedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    readonly_fields = ['user',]

    fields = (
        ('get_user_type', 'get_users'),
        ('item_name', 'quantity'),
        ('item_status','user')
    )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pdb.set_trace()
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
        # super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

@admin.register(UserProfile)
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = (
        ('username', 'email'),
        ('name','user_type'),
        ('phone_number'),
        ('is_active','is_superuser','is_staff')
    )
```

**Output**

```
-> obj.user = request.user
(Pdb) c
Internal Server Error: /admin/users/inventoryissued/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1634, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1522, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1565, in _changeform_view
    self.log_addition(request, new_object, change_message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 810, in log_addition
    object_repr=str(object),
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type UserProfile)
[30/Dec/2019 19:08:54] "POST /admin/users/inventoryissued/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 111083
```

Comment: `def __str__(self): return self.get_users` indeed seems unlikely to return a string.

Comment: get_users isn't a string.  What does ForeignKey return with those arguments?  It may be as simple as __str__ should return  str(get_users).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `get_user` is a `ForeignKey` to the user model.

If you thus define:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.get_user
```

you do *not* return a *string* (which is necessary for a `__str__` method), but a `UserProfile` object). You can however call `str(..)` over it, to convert it to a string:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.get_user)
```